# bootstrap dropdown not working in electron

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, electron

Building an electron app using Angular JS. I installed a bootstrap nav menu on the main screen that works perfectly except for the dropdown nav items, they don't drop down when clicked. The code itself is a copy and paste from the nav sample from the bootstrap site.

Here is my package.json

```
{
 "name": "testapp",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "",
 "main": "main.js",
 "scripts": {
   "start": "electron ."
 },
 "author": "",
 "license": "ISC",
 "devDependencies": {
"   electron-prebuilt": "^1.2.2"
 },
 "dependencies": {
 "angular": "^1.5.6",
  "angular-route": "^1.5.6",
  "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
 }
```

}

I installed bootstrap via NPM. In the head of my main.html I call the css from the node_module folder.

Below the body tag I have my script declarations as such:

```
 <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Again the rest of the nav items that are not dropdowns work great. Why would dropdowns not work here?

Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Do you have any errors in window dev tools?

Comment: no errors, it just didn't work.

Answer (score 6):

I just ran into the same problem.
The solution was dead simple. 
Just forgot to properly initialize JQuery onLoad.

Do something like this in your html-files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" onload="window.$ = window.jQuery = module.exports;"></script>
```

Dropdown code does not have to be added seperately for this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why but it appears I had to add the explicit bootstrap dropdown code. I added the dropdown.min.js into my bootstrap/dist/js folder and then referenced in my main.html under my call to the main bootstrap.min.js and now the drop down nav items work.

I had assumed the dropdown code was in the main bootstrap.js file? I wonder if it's common practice to have to include the dropdown js as a separate file?

Answer (score 0):

Dropdowns (in Bootstrap) are built on a third party library (Popper.js), which provides dynamic positioning and viewport detection. Be sure to include popper.min.js before Bootstrap’s JavaScript

download the source from: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js

save it to your project folder and then import it at the HTML code :

that should work